# Setting a Trendline as Variable Throws Error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working witht he following code:

```
Sub AddTrendLinesBoth()
Dim myCht As ChartObject
Dim oTren As Trendline
Dim oWb As Workbook
Dim oWS As Worksheet
Set oWb = ThisWorkbook
Set oWS = oWb.Sheets("Summary")

Set myCht = oWS.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
    On Error GoTo GetOut
With myCht.Chart
    .SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines.Add
    .SeriesCollection(2).Trendlines.Add
End With


Set oTren = myCht.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines(1)
        With oTren.Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .Weight = 3
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(112, 48, 160)
            .Transparency = 0
        End With

Set oTren = myCht.SeriesCollection(2).Trendlines(1)
        With oTren.Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .Weight = 3
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .Transparency = 0
        End With

GetOut:
End Sub
```

On each instance of `set oTren =` the code errors out on establishing the variable. What am I missing to adequately establish that line? 
The reason I'm using `with` statements as `set` variables, is because using `ActiveChart` and `ActiveSheet` was throwing method errors with older versions of Excel.

Comment: Maybe `Set oTren = myCht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines(1)` ?

Comment: That did it. Would I need to do this in the original `set myCht` line, too? or just in the latter instances?

Comment: No, though you could experiment with declaring `myCht` as a chart rather than a chart object.

Comment: Would you mind submitting this as an answer so I can mark as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `myCht` is a `ChartObject` object rather than a `Chart` object. You thus need to go through the chart object's chart method to get to the elements of the chart, such as trendlines associated to series:

```
Set oTren = myCht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines(1)
```